# android update project --path "path" error: target invalid (ubuntu)

Tags: android, ocr, tesseract, tess-two

I am trying to build tesseract library in android studio.

abhimanyu@MyPC:~/Documents/tess-two-master/tess-two$ /home/abhimanyu/Android/Sdk/tools/android update project --path .

Error: The project either has no target set or the target is invalid.
Please provide a --target to the 'android update' command.

What path to specify then? plz help

Answer (score 1):

You can install API level 8 of the Android platform, or include a `--target` parameter to avoid this error.

But a better alternative is to not try to build the project yourself, and [use](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two#usage) the library as a precompiled binary.