# Cannot update project from terminal in Android

Tags: android, terminal, android-ndk, ocr, tess-two

I am developing an Android project. In my project, I need to do OCR. So found this tutorial http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/840623/Android-Character-Recognition. I am trying to follow that tutorial. But I am having problems with set up, especially with updating project from terminal (tess-two folder). See what I have done below.

1. I downloaded tess-two from this link

   https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two/
2. Then I installed android NDK to build that project
3. I set environment variable under PATH
4. Then I run below command in tess two folder from terminal

   ```
   ndk-build //this took around 30 minutes. I closed command windows after successful built
   ```
5. Then I run this command

   ```
   android update project --path C:\tess-two-master\tess-two
   ```

The problem starts when I run that command because I cannot run android command from terminal. So I found solution from Stack Overflow. I needed to set ANDROID_HOME and environments variable under PATH. Then I tested "android" command and it is working.

6. Then I run this command again

   ```
   android update project --path C:\tess-two-master\tess-two
   ```

This time, it is giving me this error

[image]

How can I solve this error? Why my update command is not working? What is wrong with my code? I am using Windows 64 OS.

This is another way. Installing using Grandle

I tried another way to install tess-two. I installed using Gradle like this according to documentation. But I cannot access to TessDataManager because it cannot be found in project.

Gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.rmtheis:tess-two:6.0.2'
}
```

This is error

[image]

As you can see, I cannot access to TessDataManager class. How can I import that class?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/35734934. There's no need to build the library yourself.

Comment: What do u mean? I dont need to import at tess two? So how can I do? I dont want to rely on API as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tess-two project has been updated to include a pre-compliled AAR that can be [incorporated into your app](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two#usage) by editing your app's build.gradle file.

This means that you can skip the steps of importing/compiling the library yourself, and follow the usage instructions on the tess-two project. After following the usage instructions, you'll be able to refer to the tess-two classes -- including the TessBaseAPI class -- directly from your project.

Comment: Thanks. I am having a problem with that but. I edited the question. Cause I cannot access to a class that should be included in Tess Two.

Comment: When I install Tess Two, I think it does not install tesseract. Please how can I solve it?

Comment: If the TessBaseAPI class works then you did it right. TessDataManager is not part of the library.